# How to use Pivot table with date column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have a table in which information about a machine running time.

This is how the table looks like:

Date canot be fixed. (Base on seach condition date period) :

```
MachineCODE  DATE        RUNNING
-----------------------------
CNC001    2019-01-04    10
CNC001    2019-02-04    10
CNC002    2019-02-04    20
CNC003    2019-04-04     5
CNC004    2019-05-04     5
```

Is it possible to get output like this:

```
Itemcode   01/04/2019    02/04/2019  03/04/2019  04/04/2019   05/04/2019
-------------------------------------------------------------------------    
CNC001        10             10    
CNC002                       20  
CNC003                                                5
CNC004                                                             5
```

But after doing some research in Google, I have found out its possible using pivot table...  Could you please help ?

Comment: See the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle+pivot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `PIVOT`:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( MachineCODE, "DATE", RUNNING ) AS
SELECT 'CNC001', DATE '2019-01-04', 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CNC001', DATE '2019-02-04', 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CNC002', DATE '2019-02-04', 20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CNC003', DATE '2019-04-04',  5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CNC004', DATE '2019-05-04',  5 FROM DUAL
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
PIVOT  ( MAX( RUNNING ) FOR "DATE" IN (
  DATE '2019-01-04' AS "2019-01-04",
  DATE '2019-02-04' AS "2019-02-04",
  DATE '2019-03-04' AS "2019-03-04",
  DATE '2019-04-04' AS "2019-04-04",
  DATE '2019-05-04' AS "2019-05-04"
) )
```

**Output**:

> ```
> MACHINECODE | 2019-01-04 | 2019-02-04 | 2019-03-04 | 2019-04-04 | 2019-05-04
> :---------- | ---------: | ---------: | ---------: | ---------: | ---------:
> CNC001      |         10 |         10 |       null |       null |       null
> CNC002      |       null |         20 |       null |       null |       null
> CNC003      |       null |       null |       null |          5 |       null
> CNC004      |       null |       null |       null |       null |          5
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4f177e1a817bfc006ec527351fc72722)*